# How to parse .mp3 file php

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

I just retrieved some **mp3 files** from a remote server. I want to parse the `.mp3` files so that they become clickable and downloadable. Right now when I retrieve the data from the server it returns the following;

`array(3) { [0]=> string(62) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/." [1]=> string(63) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/.." [2]=> string(81) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/Country Kickin 4.mp3" }`

I just want to parse it so it becomes clickable (and downloadable), without it being plain text and with only the file name. How do I go about doing that?

**My PHP code:**

```
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");

    // get contents of the current directory
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $destination_folder);
     var_dump($contents);
    //var_dump(error_get_last($contents));

    // succesbericht
    echo "upload is gelukt";
```

There must be some kind of middleware that allows me to do this?
If the info is not enough or clear, please tell me so that I can improve the question.

**Edit**

I also tried:

```
// get contents of the current directory
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $destination_folder);

   foreach ($contents as $mp3_url) { 
     $filename = basename($mp3_url, ".mp3");
      echo "<a href='$mp3_url'>$filename</a>";
 } 
     var_dump($contents);
    //var_dump(error_get_last($contents));

    // succesbericht
    echo "upload is gelukt";
}
```

**Which returns:**

`...22nlarray(3) { [0]=> string(62) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/." [1]=> string(63) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/.." [2]=> string(69) "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/22nl.mp3" } upload is gelukt`

The `..22nl` is a link, when clicked on it says:

**Not Found**

> The requested URL
>   /public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/Albums/22nl.mp3
>   was not found on this server. Greetings,

Rezoo Aftib

Comment: That code you have shown doesn’t make much sense to begin with, that appears to be just several different rudimentary things mixed into one.

Comment: It is just a ftp_nlist that shows all the files from the directory. That is where I retrieve the data from the server.

Comment: _“It is just a ftp_nlist that shows all the files from the directory.”_ - not if you send this with a `Content-Type: audio/mpeg` header, because then the browser will expect actual video data - which your directory listing is not. // You don’t want to actually “parse” the mp3 files here, you want to do something with those file system paths you got there. Question would be - what exactly? If this is from a remote server, then you probably want to create the corresponding HTTP URLs for them first of all.

Comment: Could you give a code example of that in the answers so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the `$contents`

```
foreach ($contents as $mp3_url) { 
     $filename = basename($mp3_url, ".mp3");
     echo "<a href='$mp3_url'>$filename</a>";

 }
```

Comment: They said this was from a remote server, so `basename` won’t do - that would only be creating relative URLs here, so they would refer to content on the same server. This needs prefixing of `/wp/wp-content/…` or `/wp-content/…` with a base domain for the remote system.

Comment: Your right, the code returned a not found. The file was not found on this server

Comment: The path to the file is already declared in the variable $destination_folder.

Comment: @CBroe, can you give code example as a answer so that I can see if it works for me and accept your answer.

Comment: Altoids, do you know how I can get rid of the 3 dots before my text?